# Android studio 23.0.0 rc3 error | tried all solutions not workng

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i have searched and tried all stackover flow methods its not helping.

i get this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

when i try add (22 lolipop ) & 23.0.1  it shows **open gradle wrapper file** & **apply plugin** nothing works

```
Error:(19, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'booook' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}
dependencies {
}
```

thats what i get in end results after making changes
`http://s9.postimg.org/fzg0sie8v/image.png`  
`http://s30.postimg.org/6eepfqxtd/image.png`  
`http://s11.postimg.org/b6l12ec8z/image.png`  
`http://s11.postimg.org/b6l12ec8z/image.png`

Answer (score 0):

You are in the top level build file (first line of the file)
You should add this new content in your sub-project (usually app/build.gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from your top-level `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}
dependencies {
}
```

It is the reason of

> Error:(19, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'